# how to create a grammar for an IF conditional

Tags: octave, grammar

i have the next three examples of the syntaxis of the conditional IF in the language Octave

```
1)
    if(condition)
        body
    end
2)
    if(condition)
       body
    else
       body-alternative
    end
3) 

    if(condition)
       body
    elseif(condition)
       body
    else
       body-alternative
    end
```

in the third example there could be as many elseif´s as you want

and i have to create a grammar for these If's. So far i have the next rules

```
<IF> := if <CONDITION> <BODY> <S>
<S>  := end | else <BODY> end | <ELSEIF>
<ELSEIF> := elseif <CONDITION> <BODY> <ELSEIF> | else <BODY> end
```

but i dont know how to create the rules for the non-terminal CONDITION, any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

`<CONDITION>` is just an `<EXPRESSION>` inside of parentheses. (The expression needs to have a boolean value, but that's not a syntactic restriction; any expression is syntactically valid.)

Creating grammars for expressions is tedious and requires a detailed knowledge of the expression syntax (obviously), but they are generally pretty similar, so you should be able to find any number of examples on the internet.

Of course, you can just look at the octave grammar itself. It's written in `bison` and you can find it in the [octave mercurial repository](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/8ba8f3d22189/libinterp/parse-tree/oct-parse.in.yy).

By the way, it is not obvious from the documentation which you quote that the following is *also* a valid Octave if statement:

```
if ( condition )
  body
elseif ( condition )
  body-2
end
```

In other words, an if statement consists of an `if` clause, any number (including 0) `elseif` clauses, an optional `else` clause, and an `end`. The fact that there is an `elseif` clause does not imply that the `else` clause is required. (So it is like just about every other language which has `if` statements terminated with some kind of end marker.)

Comment: Thanks @rici, one last question if have (e-(b%4*3>2)) would it be a valid if statement(not only in octave, but in other languages)????

Comment: @user3105533: it would be syntactically correct but in some languages it would.br a type error. i don't know if octave would accept it or not, but it would reject it at runtime if it rejected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if ( the condition )
  body
elseif ( the condition )
  body second
else
  what you need
end
```